# CSS form styling doesn't display in firefox/Opera

Tags: css, wordpress, forms, firefox, opera

I've made a searchform on Wordpress. I've styled the searchform to my own taste and all seems to be working fine in Webkit browsers (Chrome & Safari) and even IE (kinda). Unfortunately Firefox and Opera completely ignore my CSS styling, it doesn't even show up in Firebug.

What can be the cause of this? I've tried -moz-appearance: none; but it makes no difference.

```
//in index.php

<span class="search">
 <?php get_search_form(); ?>
</span>



//in searchform.php

<form role="search" method="get" class="searchForm" action="<?php echo home_url( '/' ); ?>">    
 <div>
    <input type="text" value="Search" name="s" class="searchBox" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}"onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" />
 </div> 
</form>



//style.css

.search {
 float: right;
 margin: 0 0 0 10px;
 background: none;
}

form.searchForm input {
 float: left;
 margin: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0;
 width: 50px;
 height: 30px;
 border: 0;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 background: none;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family:ProximaNova-Light,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
 -webkit-transition:.2s;
 -moz-transition:.2s;
 -ms-transition:.2s;
 -o-transition:.2s;
 -webkit-appearance: none;
} 

form.searchForm input:focus {
 width: 180px;
}
```

URL: http://jorenfrielink.com/beta2/

Thank's for your help in advance. I have styled a few forms before and they worked fine in Opera and Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox seems to stop reading the css file when it hits this rule:

```
.archiveListWrap:hover > .archiveListImg img {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;
    filter: gray;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
}
```

have a look at [this article](http://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) on using svg in css

Comment: Thanks a lot! That fixed it allright. I had no idea where to look. I'll look in to the article, thanks for the tip.

Comment: In firebug you can view the css as Firefox is interpreting it by clicking the CSS tab. On your site it stopped at the `.archiveListWrap:hover > .archiveListImg img` rule, so anything after that was being ignored - http://cl.ly/P4WX

Answer (score 0):

You can change CSS like that it will work

```
.searchForm input
{
 float: left;
 margin: 0px 8px 0px 0px;
 padding: 0;
  width: 50px;
   height: 30px;
    border: 0;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
   background: none;
   color: #000;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-family:ProximaNova-Light,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
  -webkit-transition:.2s;
  -moz-transition:.2s;
  -ms-transition:.2s;
  -o-transition:.2s;
   -webkit-appearance: none;
 } 

.searchForm input:focus
{
width: 180px;
}
```